# Why aren't the fragments showing up from my navigation drawer?

Tags: android, xml, android-studio, android-fragments

Here lads, I've honestly been trying to do this every which way but for some reason the different fragments just won't show up properly. I've gotten as far to the point where a fragment shows up but its on top of the home fragment. I'm so frustrated. I've been at this for DAYS

Here's the important part of the MainActivity.java

```
 @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {


        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);


        Toolbar toolbar = findViewById(R.id.toolbar);

        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);


        drawer = findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
        NavigationView navigationView = findViewById(R.id.nav_view);
        navigationView.setNavigationItemSelectedListener(this);

        ActionBarDrawerToggle toggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(this, drawer, toolbar,
                R.string.navigation_drawer_open, R.string.navigation_drawer_close);
        drawer.addDrawerListener(toggle);
        toggle.syncState();


        if (savedInstanceState == null) {
            getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().replace(R.id.fragment_container,
                    new HomeFragment()).commit();
            navigationView.setCheckedItem(R.id.nav_home);
        }
    }





        // Passing each menu ID as a set of Ids because each
        // menu should be considered as top level destinations.
     /*   mAppBarConfiguration = new AppBarConfiguration.Builder(
                R.id.nav_home, R.id.nav_members, R.id.nav_map,
                R.id.nav_news, R.id.nav_livestream, R.id.nav_election,
                R.id.nav_share, R.id.nav_login)
                .setDrawerLayout(drawer)
                .build();
        NavController navController = Navigation.findNavController(this, R.id.nav_host_fragment);
        NavigationUI.setupActionBarWithNavController(this, navController, mAppBarConfiguration);
        NavigationUI.setupWithNavController(navigationView, navController);

        navigationView.bringToFront(); */

      // navigationView.setNavigationItemSelectedListener(new NavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener() {



    @Override
    public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(@NonNull MenuItem menuItem) {

                switch (menuItem.getItemId()) {
                    case R.id.nav_home:
                        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Home is selected", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                        getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().replace(R.id.fragment_container,
                                new HomeFragment()).commit();
                        break;

                    case R.id.nav_members:
                        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Members are selected",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

                        getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().replace(R.id.nav_host_fragment,
                                new MembersFragment()).commit();
                        break;

                    case R.id.nav_map:
                        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Map is selected", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                        FragmentManager mapfm= getSupportFragmentManager();
                        MapFragment mapFragment = new MapFragment();
                        mapfm.beginTransaction().replace(R.id.drawer_layout, mapFragment).commit();


                        break;

                    case R.id.nav_news:
                        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "News is selected", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                        Intent newsStart =new Intent(MainActivity.this, MainActivityGaeilge.class);
                        startActivity(newsStart);
                        break;

                    case R.id.nav_livestream:
                        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Livestream is selected", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

                       getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().replace(R.id.nav_host_fragment,
                               new LivestreamFragment()).commit();
                        break;

                    case R.id.nav_election:
                        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Election info is selected", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                        //Intent electionopen = new Intent(MainActivity.this, ElectionFragment.class);
                       // startActivity(electionopen);

                        FragmentManager electionfm= getSupportFragmentManager();
                        ElectionFragment electionFragment = new ElectionFragment();
                        electionfm.beginTransaction().replace(R.id.home_page, electionFragment).commit();
                        break;


                    case R.id.nav_share:
                        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Share is selected", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                        getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().replace(R.id.nav_host_fragment,
                                new SendFragment()).commit();
                        //Toast.makeText(this, "Share", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        //Intent sharestart=new Intent(MainActivity.this,this.class);
                       // startActivity(sharestart);
                        break;

                    case R.id.nav_login:
                        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Login is selected", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                        break;



                   // case R.id.nav_election:
                      //  Intent electionopen = new Intent(MainActivity.this, ElectionFragment.class);
                     //   startActivity(electionopen);
                }

                drawer.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START);

                return true;
            }

            @Override
            public void onBackPressed() {
        if (drawer.isDrawerOpen(GravityCompat.START)) {
            drawer.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
        } else {
            super.onBackPressed();
        }
            }
```

Here's the Activity_main.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.drawerlayout.widget.DrawerLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    tools:context=".MainActivity"
    tools:openDrawer="start">

    <include
        layout="@layout/app_bar_main"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" />

     <com.google.android.material.navigation.NavigationView
        android:id="@+id/nav_view"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="start"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
        app:headerLayout="@layout/nav_header_main"
        app:menu="@menu/activity_main_drawer" />

    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/fragment_container"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" />

</androidx.drawerlayout.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

Here's the app_bar_main.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:id="@+id/home_page"
    tools:context=".MainActivity"
    android:orientation="vertical">

        <com.google.android.material.appbar.AppBarLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme.AppBarOverlay">

        <androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar
            android:id="@+id/toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
            android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
            app:popupTheme="@style/AppTheme.PopupOverlay" />

    </com.google.android.material.appbar.AppBarLayout>

   <include layout="@layout/content_main" />

</androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

And here's the content_main.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
    tools:showIn="@layout/app_bar_main">

    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/nav_host_fragment"
        android:name="androidx.navigation.fragment.NavHostFragment"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        app:defaultNavHost="true"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.0"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:navGraph="@navigation/mobile_navigation" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView"
        android:layout_width="56dp"
        android:layout_height="27dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="82dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="227dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="273dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="477dp"
        android:text="Text: "
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/etUsername"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginStart="168dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="218dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="30dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="466dp"
        android:ems="10"
        android:inputType="textPersonName"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btnLogin"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginStart="138dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="328dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="149dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="355dp"
        android:onClick="OnLogin"
        android:text="Login Button"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginStart="80dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="274dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="265dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="438dp"
        android:onClick="OnLogin"
        android:text="Password:"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/etPassword"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginStart="169dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="268dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="29dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="418dp"
        android:ems="10"
        android:inputType="textPersonName"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />


</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

PLEASE HELP IM SO STRESSED

Comment: Why not you follow **template** properly from Android Studio?

Answer (score 0):

Currently you have two containers into which a `Fragment` might go:

- You use the support `FragmentManager` all over your `MainActivity` with a `FrameLayout` with `android:id="@+id/fragment_container"` to add and replace various `Fragment`s
- You seem to have set up a navigation graph, at least there is a `NavHostFragment` in *content_main.xml* and some code related to `NavController` in comments in `MainActivity`

It looks like you add `HomeFragment` twice: once as start `Fragment` in the navigation graph and the other time in `onCreate()` via the support `FragentManager`

So when you're navigating through your app, you see the `Fragment`s displayed on top of the `HomeFragment` instance in the `NavHostFragment`

Solution: use the support `FragmentManager` or the `NavController` consistently throughout your app and  remove the container which belongs to the other approach (either the `NavHostFragment` or the `FrameLayout`)

The following suggestions assume you want to use `FragmentManager`:

Remove the `FrameLayout` serving as container for the `Fragment`s from *activity_main.xml*:

```
<androidx.drawerlayout.widget.DrawerLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    tools:context=".MainActivity"
    tools:openDrawer="start">

    <include
        layout="@layout/app_bar_main"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" />

     <com.google.android.material.navigation.NavigationView
        android:id="@+id/nav_view"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="start"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
        app:headerLayout="@layout/nav_header_main"
        app:menu="@menu/activity_main_drawer" />

</androidx.drawerlayout.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

... and add it to *content_main.xml* in place of the `NavHostFragment`

```
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
    tools:showIn="@layout/app_bar_main">

  <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/fragment_container"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.0"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"/>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView"
        android:layout_width="56dp"
        android:layout_height="27dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="82dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="227dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="273dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="477dp"
        android:text="Text: "
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/etUsername"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginStart="168dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="218dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="30dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="466dp"
        android:ems="10"
        android:inputType="textPersonName"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btnLogin"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginStart="138dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="328dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="149dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="355dp"
        android:onClick="OnLogin"
        android:text="Login Button"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginStart="80dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="274dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="265dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="438dp"
        android:onClick="OnLogin"
        android:text="Password:"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/etPassword"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginStart="169dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="268dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="29dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="418dp"
        android:ems="10"
        android:inputType="textPersonName"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

Please note that you can delete the file *res/navigation/mobile-navigation.xml* since it was only used by the `NavHostFragment`